# New debian 8 install... cannot get to a terminal without a GUI

Tags: debian

**NOTE:** This is a fresh install of Debian 8 with defaults. Single user mode freezes on boot. I am trying to install Geforce 9 drivers, but cannot get to a terminal without a GUI.

For example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> thru <kbd>F6</kbd> when in GNOME causes a black screen with nothing displayed.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Boot with `nomodeset`. Probably Kernel Mode Setting (KMS) is messing around.